# vxWorks kernel shell abilities

Tags: sqlite, vxworks

I have a car navigation system installed in my car and I figured out that it's running vxWorks 6.9.3.

What I'm trying to achieve is to change some hidden settings of the nav-system.

Small introduction: Nav system have ability to connect to internet via Bluetooth. I setup small web-server the only thing it can do is detect IP address of client. I opened that web-site from head unit browser and detected ip address of head unit. Than I'm able to scan for opened network ports of it.

It turned out that it has 23 port open. And I'm able to telnet there.
It didn't required any password or login and it report operation system info: Windriver vxWorks 6.9.3

I can run various commands here, inspect filesystem, etc. 
But I don't know how I can change something. I even found the way to transfer files from USB-key from and to device.

I found that all settings which I want to change are stored in .sqlite files. Some of them are gzipped and have .inf file with check-sums. Algorithm of check-sum calculation is proprietary so I can't transfer .sqlite files from device to usb-key, change something, than gzip and calculate new check-sum.

I think OS can somehow interact with .sqlite files in-memory without ungzip them. 
So, is there any ways to open sqlite shell on device using vxWorks kernel shell? 
If yes, that would be perfect and enough to achieve anything I want.

If this can't be achieved, can somebody give me some advice of what possibilities I have from vxWorks kernel shell?

Comment: The checksums have nothing to do with the OS; you would have to interact with the component that computes the checksums.

Comment: @CL I think so. But when i'm in the telnet session there is no regular 'commads' like un UNIX. Only few pre-defined commands which looks more like c-functions call's.
i.e: copy "source", "target" 
for copying file. Notice this comma between arguments. 
And I can't get full list of such commands to look for checksum calculation program os so.

Comment: You mentioned that you can transfer files, did you try fetching the .sqlite db and modifying the content and transfer it back. Once files is transferred, reboot the device so that new .sqllite db is read. Also as mentioned by lukas use lkup functionality to check public function for eg lkup "sql". Also check if you have vxWorks command interpreter running using cmd command.

Comment: @VikashJain Yes, I have tried to modify files and transfer them back but no luck :(
I think this is because they are gzipped and have checksums for original files.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The commands available on the VxWorks shell depend on the loaded applications and the kernel itself. From the shell you can call all "public functions" loaded by VxWorks. You enter the function call in a C-like syntax and the shell parses the arguments pushes them onto the stack and jumps to the address of the function just like a normal function call in C.

A helpful function to check if a funtion exists is `lkup "foo"` which will lists all functions containing `"foo"` in their name (case sensitive!). But it doesn't tell you anything about the requested parameters. If you are not passing all parameters to the function via the shell, the intepreter pushes some zeroes onto the stack before executing the function call. This may lead to very strange results and may even damage your system (depending on the function)...

If you're able to load a program you may want to use the functions of [symLib](http://www.vxdev.com/docs/vx55man/vxworks/ref/symLib.html) to iterate all symbols of the VxWorks `sysSymTbl`.

Comment: This is very usefull, I'll try to lkup for sqlite functions